# RStudio crashes when no specific project is loaded

Tags: rstudio

I have the problem that RStudio crashes because it presumably tries to load a very big file I accidently tried to create. If I open RStudio wihtout opening a specific project the underlying process RStudio R Session uses an exessive amount of RAM (over 2 GB) and essentially freezes.  It basically opens a default project, which I can't delete because I can't find it. I can circumvent the problem by opening a different project, but I want to be able to open RStudio without opening a specific project. My idea was to find the project and delete all associated files so it doesn't try to load anything anymore.

I am using a windows 10 machine if that is of importance.

Answer (score -1):

Your "default project" is stored in your home directory. When RStudio starts up, it looks for, and reads, a file called `.RData`. If that file exists in your home directory and is large, deleting it should fix the problem!

There is a full list of all the things R does at startup here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Very likely one of these is causing the slowness, so if it's not `.RData`, you might try looking at the other things R is doing to see if one of them could be at fault.

Comment: I searched for an .RData file that could cause a problem, but I could not locate one. I ran RStudio diagnostics and found that my home is "C:/Users/XXX/Documents", but there is no .RData or anything else.

Comment: How can I change any of these settings if RStudio crashes immediately?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to implement any of these solutions. If I open R it works fine, only when I open Rstudio without opening a specific project it crashes. Can you change settings for RStudio by just opening R? However there is no .RData, which I can find, but again I did try to create a big file by accident before this problem started.

Comment: This post was not helpful at all. There is no .RData that I can delete but still I need to open a different project to work. The default project is not working and I have no way to change it.